# The song playing in ep. 54 of Boku no Hero Academia when Todoroki fought the guy that can make things big

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

I want to know the OST played at *Boku no Hero Academia* ep. 54 when Todoroki fought that guy who can make things big. The timing is 20:40 in episode 54.

I tried to find it in YouTube but failed.

What's the song?

Comment: Note: [episode 54 = season 3 episode 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_My_Hero_Academia_episodes#Season_3_(2018))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its called - Cavalry battle / Kibasen